# Posterior and Likelihood probabilities meaning

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, posterior, likelihood

I am a computer scientist, so I have a background at maths (however limited). I am reading about posterior distribution from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_distribution .

It says there:

The posterior probability is the probability of the parameters θ given the evidence X: p(θ|x).

It contrasts with the likelihood function, which is the probability of the evidence given the parameters: p(x|θ).

My question is firstly can you provide me with a very simple example to understand better these concepts? And in addition in machine learning, what we want isn't the probability p(Class|x)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: There are many many examples out there already, which you can easily find by googling.

Comment: If you define the 'parameter' $\theta$ as being $P(Class | x)$ then it's clear that that's what you actually want.  A fairly complete exposition with an ML slant is [Bishop's book](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) and a very short piece that helpfully related posteriors to likelihood functions in a classification context is [Jordan 1995](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.54.27)

Answer (score 0):

Likelihood is something that you design. 
Using Likelihood and prior you compute posterior and use it for inference.

Watch this for details: 
http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_bishop_ibi/

Comment: Thank you! "Using Likelihood and prior you compute posterior and use it for inference.", was, what I was looking for.